# Add a visualization having unique filed values on Y axis and time on x axis on kibana

Tags: logstash, kibana, kibana-4, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

I have three fields : Event (string) , Keyword (string) and Time.

Event can take specific values say A, B and C.

Now I want to have time on x axis. Event on Y axis and then on searching for a particular Keyword I want to be able to trace that which event happen over time for that particular keyword.

[image]

How can I do that on Kibana4 ? Will any other kind of visualization be better for my use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have anything but a number on Y axis.

But in the line chart you can have more than one line. The separation in multiple lines can be done with a term aggregation, so if done on the field Event, it would create three line, for A, B and C.

And in the visualisation interface you have access to the search field and you can search for a Keyword.